# Editable textfield in custom table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom tableview cell with text field and two labels

TableViewCell:

```
@interface CartTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *proCost;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtQtyCount;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTotalCost;

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
@interface CartViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
CGPoint origin = textField.frame.origin;
    CGPoint point = [textField.superview convertPoint:origin toView:self.tblView];

    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tblView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)cartCell.txtQtyCount.tag);
    [self.tblView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];

    qty = cartCell.txtQtyCount.text;
    quanty = [qty doubleValue];
    double qua = price * quanty;
    qtotal =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f",qua];
    [dictionary setObject:qtotal forKey:@"qtotal"];
    [dictionary setObject:qty forKey:@"qty"];

    [self.tblView beginUpdates];
   NSArray *indexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
    [self.tblView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
  [self.tblView endUpdates];
    [cartCell.txtQtyCount resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    cartCell =[self.tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSMutableString *name;
    name = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",
              [tmpDict objectForKey:@"name"]];


    qty = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",
             [tmpDict objectForKey:@"qty"]];

    NSString *qtot = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpDict objectForKey:@"qtotal"]];


    NSMutableString *qcost;
    qcost = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",
                [tmpDict objectForKey:@"total"]];

    cartCell.txtQtyCount.tag = indexPath.row;
    cartCell.proCost.text = qcost;
    cartCell.txtQtyCount.text = qty;
    cartCell.lblTotalCost.text = qtot;
}
```

Actually I have a `proCost` with one double value and `txtQtyCount` where I can update the quantity so I'll multiply price with quantity and want to save the multiplied value in `lblTotalCost`. I'm not clear how to get the value(indexpath) of edited row .

Comment: Could you post the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method?

Comment: Are you not returning the cell in this method, or have you removed a part?

Comment: yeah I deleted the line unfortunately but I have returned the cell in my coding

Comment: You have set the tag for the UITextField, is that not enough?

Comment: yeah but I don't have any idea how to get the value of the edited text and respective price in textfieldShouldReturn: method

Comment: For that you can directly check the Datasource array

Comment: If I edit the value in textfield then the value is getting updated in my last row

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve whatever value you need by just by looking into your updated datasource array(myObject).

Obviously you need to keep it updated so when user inputs a new quantity make sure you update the "qty" tmpDict at the same index as your textfield tag accordingly.

Comment: [((NSMutableDictionary *)[myObject objectAtIndex:textfield.tag]) setObject:(the value user typed in the textfield) forKey:@"qty"];

Answer (score 0):

Have had a similar issue to this. I figured what I really needed was the `indexPath` of that view in the correct cell

So.. I made a `UITakeView` `category` and had method like this:

```
 -(NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCellContaininView:(UIView *)view
    {
        while (view != nil){

            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){

                    return [self indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)view];
            }else {
                        view = [view superview];
            }
        }

        return nil;
    }
```

Then you could use it in `UITextFields` delegates that make sense for your use case - enable:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCellContaininView:textField];

/// do something with the index path - you have the exact cell / uitextfield being edited // 

return YES; 
}
```